Unable to navigate to the page after sign In

Error:
Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://script.google.com' from frame with URL 'https://n-x4qqieogl32dh7vitgxnysfogdq2h5ccinv5p6a-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed with the 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' flag, but has no user activation (aka gesture). See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629582019395584.

Code:
function ModelViewer(token) {
  if (!token) {
    console.log("No token found");
    return;
  }
   
      
    // Fetch the URL dynamically
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (appUrl) {
    console.log("Fetched URL:", appUrl);

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (isValid) {
    if (isValid) {
      console.log("isValid it is!")
      console.log("Token", token);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = `${appUrl}?page=Models&token=${token}`;
      link.id = 'linkURL';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      document.getElementById('linkURL').click();

    } else {
      console.log("isValid",isValid);
      console.log("Token", token);
      console.log("Invalid token. Redirecting to SignIn.");
      showNotification("Session expired. Please sign in again.", "error");
      }
    }).validateToken(token);
  }).getAppUrl(); // Call the server-side function to get the URL
}


Welcome to Stackoverflow! Have you tried using windows.open("enter-your-link")

As the sandbox name, allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' says, you can't navigate to another page without a user interaction. The link needs to clicked by the end user with the target attribute set to the top frame.
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = `${appUrl}?page=Models&token=${token}`;
  link.id = 'linkURL';
  link.target = '_top'
  link.innerText = 'Signed in! Click Here to continue!'
  document.body.appendChild(link); //No auto click possible 


But if i dont add this  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (isValid) {
then the url page can be easily opened without the need of login or credentials. User can easily paste the url above and it will show the model page without login

@Dhruv So add google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(... but instead of redirecting, add a link to the new page. That's what my code suggests. It doesn't suggest to remove google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...
